# Is it possible to deduce the tiles each player has just by viewing the tiles played for an entire Scrabble game?

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming

Given as input the tiles used by each player for every turn and the tiles each player has left at the end of the game, disregarding the possibility of swapping all of the tiles for a turn, is it possible to deduce the tiles each player has for each turn of a game of Scrabble?

Just to clarify, you have full knowledge of all of the plays, so you know exactly which plays make every word. The question is,  can you can work backwards from the end of the game with complete play information to know the tiles each player has earlier in the game?

Comment: what you can do is compute probability of tiles that are not used yet from the tiles used and tiles known that someone has...

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  Most layouts are not susceptible to retrograde analysis: there are multiple draws and plays that will lead to the same board configuration.  For instance, given only a single word in the middle "PATER", you have no idea whether that was a single play or up to five plays.

Your second question is significantly off-topic (too broad) for Stack Overflow.

---

Got it; my mistake earlier.

No, the unplayed tiles are not generally susceptible to retrograde analysis.  Consider merely the first three plays of ASTER, DOU(R), and (S)HOWBOAT.  Of those seven letters player 1 just laid, you have no way of knowing which two were in the original rack, and which were drawn after playing ASTER.

The only time you know exactly what seven tiles a player had at a given turn is when all seven are revealed on the play (or end of game).

Comment: You have full knowledge of all of the plays, so you would know exactly which plays made every word.  The question is whether you can work backwards from the end with complete play information to know the tiles each player has earlier in the game.